# How to generate HTML for JSDoc

Tags: javascript, documentation-generation, jsdoc

I'd like to create an auto generating JSDoc documentation file for a framework I'm building but can't seem to find a way to output the documentation.
Is it possible to output the doc to JSON or HTML? Or will I have to build my own JSDoc parser with RegExp?

I've looked all over the web and can't find anything on the subject.

Thank you.

Comment: Uhm: *"Once your code is commented, you can use the JSDoc 3 Tool to generate an HTML website from the source. By default, JSDoc will use the "default" template to turn the documentation data into HTML. You can edit this template to suit your own needs, or create an entirely new template if that is what you prefer. `./jsdoc book.js`
 This command will create a folder named "out" in the current working directory. Within that you will find the generated HTML pages."* http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html ... seems like you looked all over the web but not the official documentation?

Comment: Always have a look at the official documentation first.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you! I've been looking for the past 3 days... Never found that page.

Comment: The JSDoc documentation is terrible IMO. Kinda funny.

Comment: Try Docma - http://onury.github.io/docma

Comment: Strange that there's no information on that jsdoc site, on where to download the actual tool/binary

Comment: since JsDoc3 requires nodeJS, it would be nice if anybody knows an alternative

Comment: I stumbled upon the original question when seeking an example of what the generated HTML looked like after I read [the official JSDoc documentation](https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html#generating-a-website). To anyone who is here for the same reason of looking for an example, Bob's your uncle: [Automate JavaScript API Documentation with JSDoc](https://alligator.io/js/jsdoc/) has examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>A big thanks to Felix Kling for pointing me the official documentation: [usejsdoc.com](http://usejsdoc.org/about-getting-started.html)</s>

The documentation has been moved to https://jsdoc.app/

Comment: According to [this issue in the jsdoc Github repo](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1642), the official documentation has now been moved to https://jsdoc.app/