# How to properly document a React/Redux application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm currently documenting a React/Redux application written in ES6 and I cannot find any useful information what's the most properly way to document a React application.

In this [post](http://davidboyne.co.uk/2016/05/26/automating-react-documentation.html), the tool [react-docgen](https://github.com/reactjs/react-docgen) is presented, and I have stumble upon [esdoc](https://esdoc.org/) as well. Whereas *esdoc* does automatic generation of documentation, *react-docgen* extracts the information of the React components and puts it into a `JSON` file.

As my application is not only React, but also Redux, I cannot find the best way to document the application. Generally speaking, I don't think that I should mix both of them and I think *esdoc* suits me better, but I'm not fully convinced what should I be documenting with *esdoc* as of lifecycle hooks, proptypes, own methods, etc..

Has anyone stumbled upon this problem and can tell me what's a proper way of documenting such an application?

Answer (score 10):

Some tools for documenting your ES6 application:

### [documentationjs](http://documentation.js.org/)

Documentationjs is a new documentation generator. It supports ES6 and allows you to write your doc comments in standard JSDoc format.

### [ESDoc](https://esdoc.org/)

ESDoc supports JSDoc syntax, parses most of ES6 and outputs nice and it integrates [Mocha](http://mochajs.org/).

### [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/)

JSDoc supports ES6 partially.

Comment: documentation.js is fantastic! thanks for introducing it

Comment: although the tools are good and I do use them, my question was not about tooling but rather about what to document of an application. I can't accept it as a valid answer but I consider your links useful so I upvoted it

Comment: Also looking for this.  There does not seem to be any standards.  We don't need UML, but what else is there?  The ref links are just for 'javadoc' type of docs.  That doesn't give structure of an app, etc.